# Is that possible to make the numerator looks nicer by centering the two lines in numerator?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=2:2]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ upgreek }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\lim_{\Updelta t\to0} P\bigg[\splitfrac{
\text{an individual fails in the interval} (t, t+\Updelta t),}{\text{given the individual has survived to t} }\bigg]}
{\Updelta t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Off topic: The Symbol is just \Delta and it is easier to be read like \Delta. On topic: Answer.

Comment: Capital Greek letters are upright by default.

Comment: @koleygr Maybe, the OP wants to use the same font for lower- and uppercase upright Greek letters.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I can't get your point... Does Updelta uses other font than \Delta? (+1 by the way)

Comment: @koleygr Package `upgreek` reports the font used in the `.log` file: ` Using Euler Roman for upright Greek`. Package options `Symbol` or `Symbolsmallscale` switch to Adobe Symbol. Both are not Computer Modern.

Comment: Aside: Shouldn't the term `\lim_{\Updelta t\to0}` be located outside, i.e., *before* the `\frac{...}{...}` expression?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I don' see the reason why not to use a tabular inside the equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=2:2]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ upgreek }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\lim_{\Delta t\to 0} P\biggl[
\begin{tabular}{c}
an individual fails in the interval $(t, t+\Delta t)$,\\
given the individual has survived to t
\end{tabular}
\biggr]}
{\Delta t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Feel free to ask me delete... (I don't know what is the numerator and the splitfrac)

Comment: thanks! but why my [ and ] is not as big as yours although i just copy your code? it cannot cover all the words

Comment: I don't know ... May be your latex version is outdated or something... Did you tried other commands like \left[ and right]? I just recompiled the code and I use latex from TeX live 2016/Debian... The output is what you see.... May be you have to run the code on sherelatex or somewhere to see that the problem is local on your pc

Comment: Welcome... But you have to try again to find the problem in your installation. (I updated some times... may be you copied between updates...)

Answer (score 3):

Macro `\substack` helps, the text is automatically centered, also the size is smaller. The size of the brackets is automatically chosen by `\left` and `\right`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{%
  \lim_{\Updelta t\to0}
  P\left[
  \substack{%
    \text{an individual fails in the interval} (t, t+\Updelta t),\\
    \text{given the individual has survived to t}
  }
  \right]
}
{\Updelta t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]